# Update source code without direct access to server

Tags: update, source

I built a webapplication (php/java) for a museum in the Netherlands.
The webaplication runs on an ArchArm Raspberry 3.
I installed a local webserver (lighttpd) to avoid dependency of the application on an internetconnection.

The Raspberry is able to talk to the internet, but I can't (ssh) reach the device remotely, because ports on the router cannot be changed.

The challenge for me is now to remotely update the webapplication's source code, without direct access to the source code.

I was thinking to use a cron script on the device, that would invoke 'rsync' to check if there were file differences, and if 'Yes' update them on the Raspberry.

My question is:
Which workaround/method would you chose in this situation?

Comment: Questions regarding Rasberry Pi and Raspbian are [off-topic](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5586/are-raspberrypis-ever-on-topic-for-serverfault) here at Server Fault.

Comment: @Paul I see this as a question about remote management of devices which happen to be in a location with limited network access. I would consider that to be on-topic for this site. It is a system administration question (and a hard one at that). That the device in question happens to be running Raspbian is not important if the same methods you'd apply to other Debian based systems work here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use its native package manager with cron, like yum-cron, to keep it updated. You could have your own repository. But of course, this probably requires an internet connection, or at least networking.

Or checkout from a git like repository on a cron schedule, then manage your source code centrally like that.